# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" using JSON and UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am importing data from a website using TouchJson. This data is supposed to be viewed in a UITableVIew. The app is a Tab Bar based app. When I run the app it crashed with the following error, throwing an exception in the following line:

```
Error: [__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Code: cell.textLabel.text = [recipeSection objectAtIndex:row];

My cellForRowAtIndexPath's source code is found here: http://pastebin.com/s3xr4NTc

The JSON I use is found here: http://muncken.myftp.org/eatstrong2/iphone/recipeList.php

My target is to show the recipes as an indexed UITableView, but I am doing it stepwise.

Comment: How are you filling `recipeSection`?

Comment: Looking at the Json i feel [recipeSection objectAtIndex:row] implies to value of a dictionary.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://pastebin.com/QfGCbms6 - This is my viewDidLoad in which I fill the recipes dictionary. Deepak: View the link that shows the source for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a method (selector) isEqualToString on an NSDictionary object.  This doesn't support the isEqualToString method - hence the error.

Comment: I think I might have figured it out now. My JSON has been changed (muncken.myftp.org/eatstrong2/iphone/recipeList.php) so that the key contains an array of strings and not dictionaries. It now works as it should. Thank you for your help guys, I apreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to use a method of an NSArray `objectAtIndex` on a NSCFDictioanry object. It will happen if at this line:

```
NSArray *recipeSection = [recipes objectForKey:key];
```

your `objectForKey` returns `NSDictionary` instead of expected NSArray.

Comment: Well, I am on thin ground here cause I'm pretty new to iPhone development and this is my first application using JSON. I intend to create a dictionary with letters (a,b,c) as keys and arrays containing recipes as values for the keys. This should be created from the above json link in my viewDidLoad (http://pastebin.com/QfGCbms6)